# Malformed JSON missing a comma separator, Insert comma in R

Tags: r, dataframe, gsub

I'm new to R and have a json file, containing data I'm hoping to convert to an R dataframe, that's been scraped in the following format:
[image]

The picture indicates where the data was scraped incorrectly, as no commas were inserted to separate entries. I've tried reading the data in with scan and separating into a list (to then read into a df) with this code:

```
indices <- grep(":[{",x, fixed=TRUE)

n <- length(indices)
l <- vector("list", n);
for(i in 1:n) {
  ps <- substr(x ,indices[[i]], indices[i+1])  ## where i is whatever your Ps is
  l[[i]] <- ps
}
```

But am getting empty string and NAN values. I've tried parsing with jsonlite, tidyjson, rjson, without any luck (which makes sense since the json is malformed). This article seems to match my json's structure, but the solution isn't working because of the missing commas. How would I insert a comma before every instance of "**{"entries":[**" in R when the file is read in as one string?

UPDATE: first, second and third entries

```
{"entries":[{"url":"/leonardomso/playground","name":"playground","lang":"TypeScript","desc":"Playground using React, Emotion, Relay, GraphQL, MongoDB.","stars":5,"forks":"2","updated":"2021-03-24T09:35:44Z","info":["react","reactjs","graphql","typescript","hooks","apollo","boilerplate","!DOCTYPE html \"\""],"repo_url":"/leonardomso?tab=repositories"}
{"entries":[{"url":"/leonardomso/playground","name":"playground","lang":"TypeScript","desc":"Playground using React, Emotion, Relay, GraphQL, MongoDB.","stars":5,"forks":"2","updated":"2021-03-24T09:35:44Z","info":["react","reactjs","graphql","typescript","hooks","apollo","boilerplate","!DOCTYPE html \"\""],"repo_url":"/leonardomso?tab=repositories"}
{"entries":[{"url":"/shiffman/Presentation-Manager","name":"Presentation-Manager","lang":"JavaScript","desc":"Simple web app to manage student presentation schedule.","stars":17,"forks":"15","updated":"2021-01-19T15:28:55Z","info":[]},{"desc":"","stars":null,"forks":"","info":[]},{"url":"/shiffman/A2Z-F20","name":"A2Z-F20","lang":"JavaScript","desc":"ITP Course Programming from A to Z Fall 2020","stars":40,"forks":"31","updated":"2020-12-21T13:52:58Z","info":[]},{"desc":"","stars":null,"forks":"","info":[]},{"desc":"","stars":null,"forks":"","info":[]},{"url":"/shiffman/RunwayML-Object-Detection","name":"RunwayML-Object-Detection","lang":"JavaScript","desc":"Object detection model with RunwayML, node.js, and p5.js","stars":16,"forks":"2","updated":"2020-11-15T23:36:36Z","info":[]},{"url":"/shiffman/ShapeClassifierCNN","name":"ShapeClassifierCNN","lang":"JavaScript","desc":"test code for new tutorial","stars":11,"forks":"1","updated":"2020-11-06T15:02:26Z","info":[]},{"url":"/shiffman/Bot-Code-of-Conduct","name":"Bot-Code-of-Conduct","desc":"Code of Conduct to guide ethical bot making practices","stars":15,"forks":"1","updated":"2020-10-15T18:30:26Z","info":[]},{"url":"/shiffman/Twitter-Bot-A2Z","name":"Twitter-Bot-A2Z","lang":"JavaScript","desc":"New twitter bot examples","stars":26,"forks":"2","updated":"2020-10-13T16:17:45Z","info":["hacktoberfest","!DOCTYPE html \"\""],"repo_url":"/shiffman?tab=repositories"}
```

Comment: It is probably not requiring a regex, try using `gsub('}{"entries":[', '},{"entries":[', x, fixed=TRUE)`

Comment: @wiktor Thank you so much! That looks to have fixed it. If you'd like to submit that as an answer, go ahead! I did have a follow up question as to why a lexical error is being through on the first space encountered in the file? My code and the error is as follows: > df <- fromJSON(y)
Error: lexical error: invalid character inside string.
          TypeScript","desc":"Playground using React, Emotion, Relay, 
                     (right here) ------^ (the commend moves the pointer, but it points right to the space between Playground and using, which is the first space in the file)

Comment: I think the parser just stops at the place where the further parsing becomes impossible.

Comment: Your data could be in [ndjson](https://ndjson.org) format. Try using `jsonlite::stream_in` if that's the case

Comment: @Hong omg that's exactly what it is! According to the docs, ndjson recognizes each new record by a "\n" character? Would I need to insert that for the file to be read properly? Right now, just doing this: "jsonlite::stream_in("myfile.json")" throws "Error: Argument 'con' must be a connection.". Would I read in the file and insert a newline character like this? "y<-gsub('}{"entries"','}\n{"entries"', x, fixed=TRUE)" and then read to a df like this? "df <- jsonlite::fromJSON(y)"

Comment: Not quite: `df <- jsonlite::stream_in(textConnection(y))`

Comment: There must be some other issue because I'm now getting: "Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : invalid multibyte string, element 1". I edited the question to show how the first, second and third entries look.

Comment: That is probably a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark Did you open the file in Notepad or some other Windows editor?

Comment: @Hong I did open the file in Notepad. Would that insert a Byte order mark? If so, how would I fix that? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: If you saved the file in Notepad, it would insert the BOM. To remove it, you'll need to use another editor. You could try VSCode: open it, change the file type to "UTF-8", and save it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```r
gsub('}{"entries":[', '},{"entries":[', x, fixed=TRUE)
```

So, this is a plain replacement of all `{"entries":[` with `},{"entries":[`.

Note the `fixed=TRUE` parameter that disables the regex engine parsing the string.